# Spring boot app deployed into PCF rendering two different response for same input

Tags: spring-boot, pcf

Our Rest API is deployed into PCF and there are 4 instances. We are observing below issue,

If one user is hitting the API 1000 times with the same input and at the SAME TIME if another user is hitting the API 500 times with different input, the second user is getting expected response for all 500 requests...but the first user is getting expected response for 999 or 998 requests and receiving second user response for one or two requests (mismatch).

Is this the case - one of the instances behind the load balancer is not responding to the updated change in one or two requests?

Comment: Please suggest on this.

Comment: If there is a mismatch in response, you need to check whether you have implemented fix for IDOR in your code. A more refined answer for this scenario can be given only after getting more details on the issue. So, please add more details about the infra being used as well as the authentication and authorization mechanism in your application

Comment: Our application doesn't contains UI and other applications are consuming our Rest API. There is a default group, if the application ID is part of that group then only they can access our application. Response mismatch is not seen all the time, when two requests are sent to the API at the same time without any milliseconds time difference then only we are observing the mismatch with only one consumer.

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: At this point of time, it is quite difficult to point out what could have gone wrong without seeing the code. From your description, it looks like you are facing issues while performing load/performance testing on the APIs. You've mentioned that there are 4 instances of the application in PCF but have not mentioned if they are using same DB instance or not. Nevertheless, it would be good to inspect the code to see whether methods are thread safe. TBH, This looks more like a concurrency issue rather than one related to load balancer.